# Can I create a password for one sheet in google sheet by using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, passwords

I having a problem with Google app script. I want to copy the data from sheet1 to sheet2 but I want sheet2 to be locked. So I intend to write the code like

Code 1 : update the password for sheet2
Code 2:  unlock password --) copy—) lock again

But I found that google sheet don’t let user apply password to sheet. It only can set the status of the user like readonly or can fully edit. So Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question.

Comment: Hi there @HoangNamNgo! Please follow the recommended guidelines and share the script code.

Comment: I have found the suitable solution for my problem thanks you

Comment: I am glad you solved this issue. For documentation purposes, could you please describe your fix in an answer?